# Is there any way of generating fixed-length sequences with RNNs?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, generative-model

Is there any way of generating fixed-length sequences with RNNs? I want to tell my character level RNN to generate a name of length 3, 4, 5 and so on. I haven't found anything online like this, but my intuition tells me that, if I append the sequence length (e.g. 5) at each RNN input, the RNN should be able to do this. Does anyone know if this task is possible?

Comment: What is the downstream case? Are you just generating from nothing, but want the random generated name to be a specific length?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it